# trendline in R in ggplot

Tags: r, trendline

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000"))
```

To this I am trying to add a trend line which is for all categories because , if I add a trend line `geom_smooth(method="lm")`, it draws for 2 seater separately which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

Override the `colour` aesthetic, which is the grouping aesthetic,  with `group = 1` in the call to `geom_smooth`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1),
              method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `geom_smooth` inherits the `aes` arguments from ggplot.  You can move 'colour' to geom_point, or pass `inherit.aes = F` to geom_smooth.

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(, colour = Color)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000"))  + geom_smooth(method = 'lm')

#or:
mpg %>% 
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2seater" = "#992399", "Other" = "#000000")) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', inherit.aes = F, aes(displ, hwy))
```

[image]